# Symfony3 Formulario para cambiar el password Error @SecurityAssert\UserPassword

Tags: symfony3

Tengo un problema con el tipico formulario para cambiar el password en el que primero le pongo que ponga su password actual.

La teoria es muy sencilla y viene explicada en la doc de symfony pero me da un error como que el password actual es incorrecto

en mi entity tengo

```
/**
 * @SecurityAssert\UserPassword(
 *     message = "Error al poner la contraseña actual"
 * )
 */
private $oldPassword;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "No puedes dejar el password vacio")
 * @Assert\Length(min = 6)
 */
private $password;
```

​el fomType  he puesto

```
->add('oldPassword', PasswordType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Ponga su password actual',
                'mapped' => false,
                ))
->add('password', RepeatedType::class, array(
                "required" => "required",
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'invalid_message' => 'Los dos password deben coincidir',
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'Password nuevo', "attr" 
=> array("class" => "form-password form-control")),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repita el Password nuevo', "attr" => array("class" => "form-password form-control"))
                    )
            )
```

​
​Y poco mas hay que hacer​ (creo) ademas de en el controler crear la vista con el formulario y luego recoger los datos del nuevo password, etc, pero como digo, me manda error de no valido el campo que comprueba el password y no se si es porque el password lo guardo encriptado 
en mi security.yml lo tengo como

```
security:
    encoders:
        BackendBundle\Entity\Users:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 4
```

Edito para añadir el action

```
public function passAction(Request $request) {


    $userId = $this->getUser(); //metemos  id  del usuario sacado de su sesión
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user_repo = $em->getRepository("BackendBundle:Users");
    $user = $user_repo->find($userId); // buscamos este usuario


    $form = $this->createForm(UsersPassType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $factory = $this->get("security.encoder_factory"); // llamamos al servicio para usar el mismo tipo de encriptación
            $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user); // llamamos al objeto user
            $password = $encoder->encodePassword($form->get("password")->getData(), $user->getSalt()); //codifciamos la password que ha llegado por el formulario

            $user->setPassword($password);

            $em->persist($user);
            $flush = $em->flush();
            if ($flush === null) {
                $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'El usuario se ha editado correctamente');
                return $this->redirectToRoute("demokratian_index_user"); //redirigimos la pagina si se incluido correctamete
            } else {
                $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('warning', 'Error al editar el passwordo');
            }
        } else {
            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('warning', 'El password no se ha editado por un error en el formulario !');
        }
    }

    return $this->render("BackendBundle:Others:editPass.html.twig", array(
                "form" => $form->createView()));
}
```

​Bueno, ¿alguien me puede ayudar?​​​ ¿tengo que indicar de alguna manera al  ​SecurityAssert​  que compruebe el password encriptado?​ ¿estoy cometiendo algún otro error?
Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda

Añado por sugerencia en el comentario de Jakala (muchas gracias) el dump($form->getErrors()) en el else del $form->isValid()  a ver si da alguna pista

```
-children: OrderedHashMap {#680 ▼
  -elements: array:2 [▼
    "oldPassword" => Form {#687 ▼
      -config: FormBuilder {#681 ▶}
      -parent: Form {#688}
      -children: OrderedHashMap {#682 ▶}
      -errors: array:1 [▼
        0 => FormError {#746 ▼
          #messageTemplate: "Error al poner la contraseña actual"
          #messageParameters: []
          #messagePluralization: null
          -message: "Error al poner la contraseña actual"
          -cause: ConstraintViolation {#994 ▼
            -message: "Error al poner la contraseña actual"
            -messageTemplate: "Error al poner la contraseña actual"
            -parameters: []
            -plural: null
            -root: Form {#688}
            -propertyPath: "data.oldPassword"
            -invalidValue: null
            -constraint: UserPassword {#934 ▶}
            -code: null
            -cause: null
          }
          -origin: Form {#687}
        }
      ]
      -submitted: true
      -clickedButton: null
      -modelData: "00004311"
      -normData: "00004311"
      -viewData: "00004311"
      -extraData: []
      -transformationFailure: null
      -defaultDataSet: true
      -lockSetData: false
    }
```

Comment: Añade un var_dump($form->getErrors()) en el else del $form->isValid(), a ver si nos da mas información.

Comment: Hola  muchas gracias, ya lo he intentado y he puesto varios dump() en distintos sitios pero la verdad es que no me da ninguna pista. De todas formas edito el post y añado el dump de error

Answer (score 0):

Después de darle muchas vueltas y gracias a la ayuda de  **@Spunc**  en el stackoverflow en ingles he conseguido que funcione. 
Pongo el código completo por su algún otro usuario tiene problemas y lo necesita

**passControler**

```
namespace BackendBundle\Controller;

use BackendBundle\Entity\Users;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class PassController extends Controller {
public function passAction(Request $request) {
    $changePasswordModel = new ChangePassword();
    $form = $this->createForm(ChangePasswordType::class, $changePasswordModel);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $user = $this->getUser(); //metemos como id la del usuario sacado de su sesion
            $encoder = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);
            $password = $encoder->encodePassword($changePasswordModel->getPassword(), $user->getSalt());
            $user->setPassword($password);
            $em->persist($user);
            $flush = $em->flush();
            if ($flush === null) {
                $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'El usuario se ha editado correctamente');
                return $this->redirectToRoute("others_show"); //redirigimos la pagina si se incluido correctamete
            } else {
                $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('warning', 'Error al editar el password');
            }
        } else {
           // dump($form->getErrors());
            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('warning', 'El password no se ha editado por un error en el formulario !');
        }
    }

    return $this->render('BackendBundle:Others:editPass.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
}
```

model **ChangePassword**

```
namespace BackendBundle\Form\Model;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Validator\Constraints as SecurityAssert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class ChangePassword {

/**
 * @SecurityAssert\UserPassword(
 *     message = "Error al poner la contraseña actual"
 * )
 */
protected $oldPassword;

/**
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min = 6,
 *     minMessage = "El password tiene que tener al menos 6 caracteres"
 * )
 */
protected $password;


public function getOldPassword() {
    return $this->oldPassword;
}

public function setOldPassword($oldPassword) {
    $this->oldPassword = $oldPassword;
    return $this;
}


public function getPassword() {
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword($password) {
    $this->password = $password;
    return $this;
}

}
```

**ChangePasswordType**

```
namespace BackendBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;

class ChangePasswordType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
                ->add('oldPassword', PasswordType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Ponga su password actual',
                ))
            ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, array(
                "required" => "required",
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'invalid_message' => 'Los dos password deben coincidir',
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'Password nuevo', "attr" => array("class" => "form-password form-control")),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repita el Password nuevo', "attr" => array("class" => "form-password form-control"))
                    )
            )
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\UserBundle\Form\Model\ChangePassword',
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'change_passwd';
}
}
```